# Puppeteer-firefox headless mode does not support webgl

Tags: firefox, automation, automated-tests, puppeteer, selenium-firefoxdriver

Puppeteer-firefox headless mode does not support webgl. What can I do in linux to make it work? 
I do not know if the selenium firefox has the same problem, I think this is firefox side error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a not yet solved issue in Firefox. You can find details about its implementation status at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375585.

And please don't use the `puppeteer-firefox` package anymore. It has been deprecated. Experimental support for Firefox is included in the official `puppeteer` package.